# how to assign product views count to its supplier to get most viewed supplier - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have manufacturers who show their products in my website and I need to track which manufacturer is most viewed one. I'm already tracking daily product views.

So imagine that I have a comma separated manufacturer ids:

```
$mfIds = '120,125,126,127';
```

Each manufacturer is a post which has a custom field with comma separated product ids. So I could get a combined array of them containing manufacturer ID as a key and array if product ids as that key value:

```
$array = explode(',', $mfIds);
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $current_mf_product_ids = get_post_meta( $value, 'current_mf_product_ids', true );
    if($current_mf_product_ids){
        $new_array[$value] = explode(',', $current_mf_product_ids);
    }
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

And this outputs the below:

```
array(4) {
  [120]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "12"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "13"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "16"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "15"
  }
  [125]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "34"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "67"
  }
  [126]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "57"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "188"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "230"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "240"
  }
  [127]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "261"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "263"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "264"
  }
}
```

Now I need to find each product views from database and sum each manufacturer products views so that I can see which manufacturer is most viewed:

```
if($new_array){
    $cmpProductArray = array();
    foreach($new_array as $key=>$ids){
        foreach($ids as $id){
            global $wpdb; 
            $today = getdate();
            $currentYear = $today["year"];
            $lastMonth = $today["mon"]-1;
            $getProductViews = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(total_views_count) as views_count, page_id FROM daily_total_views WHERE page_id = '".$id."' AND year(date) = '".$currentYear."' AND month(date) = '".$lastMonth."' group by page_id");
            if($getProductViews){
                $getEncodedProducts = json_decode(json_encode($getProductViews), True);
                foreach($getEncodedProducts as $item){
                    $cmpProductArray[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Via above code I'm getting each product total views. But don't know now how to connect each product views with the above array so that can see which manufacturer how many views has. Any ideas please?

Comment: Watch out.  You have an SQL call inside 2 levels of `foreach`.  It might perform okay in development with only 4 mfgs and 4 products each (16 SQL queries) but in production with, say, 100 mfgs with 1000 products each you'd be looking at 100,000 SQL queries ... which likely won't perform well enough.

Comment: Usually best to let the database do all the work.  Is the list of manufacturers and their product ids available in a table in MySQL?

Comment: they are in separate tables. How I told I am using wordpress. So manufacturers are a single post type and its product ids are again single post type posts and they are being connected to the supplier by custom field. I have comma separated product ids in a custom field @BareNakedCoder

Comment: Ah, Wordpress.  I'm only a little familiar with that.  I did go to Wordpress doc and read about the `get_post_meta` function and see what you mean.  The list of product ids is in the database but in a comma-separated list in a meta data field of a Wordpress "post" entity (not easy to get at with an SQL query).  But I guess this means you are unlikely to have a huge number (1000) of products per manufacturer.

Comment: yes products will be added of course by the time. That's why want to figure this out in a productive way @BareNakedCoder

Comment: do you have any ideas please? @BareNakedCoder

Comment: finally found a solution @BareNakedCoder